# Multi Level pivoting of dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have this dataframe:

| Group | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | Class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 5 | 4 | 1 |
| Second | 5 | 5 | 0 |
| First | 1 | 2 | 0 |

I want to do a multi level pivot in pandas to have something like this:

```
Group |  Feature1 (class 1)| Feature (Class 2)  |  Feature2 (Class 1) | Feature 1(Class 2)
```

What if I want to select only one feature to work with?

Comment: What does your expected output look like with these data?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
out = (df.assign(Class=df["Class"]+1)
         .pivot(index="Group", columns="Class"))

print(out)
       Feature 1      Feature 2
Class          1    2         1    2
Group
First        1.0  5.0       2.0  4.0
Second       5.0  NaN       5.0  NaN
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the solution, however, I receive an error, 'ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'

Comment: This means that your "Group" column is not unique. To satisfy non-unique groupings (e.g. where 2 or more rows contain the value "First"), you can use the `pd.pivot_table` instead of `pivot`. This method allows an `aggfunc` which will aggregate rows with repeat index values. (e.g. to properly handle duplicate rows that belong to the "First" group, you can average their values before pivoting.)